# ScrollTop não funciona após certa rolagem

Tags: jquery, css

Tenho uma `div` chamada **busca**, quero que após o `ScrollTop 100`, ele fique fixo.

Não está funcionando.

```
var $w = $(window);

$w.on("scroll", function(){
   if( $w.scrollTop() > 100 ) {
        $('busca').css("position", "fixed");
   }
   else{
        $('busca').css("position", "static");
   }

});
```

Comment: Aparece algum erro no console? Tenta pegar o valor do scrollTop e dar um console e vê o resultado...

Comment: @DiegoSantos inclui o console.log no if e ele retornou certo. console.log("Maior que 100");

Comment: Pera, seu elemento não chama busca... Não falta um ponto antes? ou uma hashtag? Tipo $('#busca').css("position", "fixed"); ???

Comment: Felipe acho que da pra resolver isso só com CSS, a não ser que vc quera mesmo usar jQuery... Se quiser posto um exemplo simples pra fazer isso com 5 linhas de CSS...

Comment: @DiegoSantos era isso sim.

Comment: @hugocsl pode ser sim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu codigo possui alguns erros
primeiro  sue selector busca deve ser um ID ou Class então deve ser "#busca" ou ".busca"
segundo variaveis em  javascript não tem $ então o codigo deve ficar assim

```
var w = $(window);

w.on("scroll", function(){
   if( w.scrollTop() > 100 ) {
        $('.busca').css("position", "fixed");
   }
   else{
        $('.busca').css("position", "static");
   }

});
```

**EDIT**

Talvez funcione melhor assim definindo  top:0 z-index um nivel  a cima dos demais

```
    var w = $(window);

w.on("scroll", function(){
   if( w.scrollTop() > 100 ) {
        $('.busca').css({"position":"fixed", "top":"0px","z-index":"1"});
   }
   else{
        $('.busca').css({"position": "static"});
   }

});
```

Comment: Provavelmente esta correto!

Comment: Vc chutou e acertou, mas ele poderia estar usando uma tag personalizada e o lance da variável com $ não influi em nada. :/

Answer (score 1):

Conforme mensionado no comentário, e dentro do que eu entendi da pergunta, acho que esse exemplo com CSS pode te ajudar caso não pretenda usar o jQuery etc.

Nesse exemplo o elemento está a `100px do topo`, e quando vc der o `scroll` ele vai parar a `50px do topo`. *Deixei os comentários no código.*

```css
body {
    height: 200vh;
}
.teste {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 100px; /* altura que está do topo */
    top: 50px; /* altura que vai parar antes do topo */
    position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<div class="teste"></div>
```